# Psycopg2 shows error

Tags: python, psycopg2

From my understanding psycopg2 comes installed with the Python 2.7. When I run the following module it returns an error.

```
import psycopg2
import sys

conn = none

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:/Programming/psycopg2.py", line 1, in<module>
import psycopg2
File "C:/Programming\psycopg2.py", line 4, in<module>
conn = none
NameError: name 'none' is not defined
```

Comment: it's `None` not `none`

Comment: Your file is called `psycopg2.py`, this means that Python won't be able to import another module called `psycopg2` from somewhere else.  Rename your script.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "none" is a [built in constant](https://docs.python.org/2/library/constants.html) which needs to be capitalised:

```
import psycopg2
import sys

conn = None
```

The error occurs because the Python interpreter thinks you are trying to reference a variable named 'none' which does not exist in your code.

Comment: I've edited the original post to reflect the challenges I'm currently facing.

Comment: StackOverflow does not work like a discussion forum.  The idea is you post a single question for a single well-defined problem and the answers are left there for you and others to see.  You should revert your edit and, as I suggested before, post any new problems in new questions.

Comment: Thanks for correcting I'm new to this community and learning the dos and donts. I'll edit the post to the first one and post a new question. Thanks.